# How to sum specific vectors in a list in R

Tags: r, vector

I know this should be simple but I just can't do it...I have a data frame called data that works nicely and does what I want it to with the correct column headers and everything. I can call colSums() to get a list of 21 numbers which are the sums of each column.

```
> a <-  colSums(data,na.rm = TRUE)
> names(a) <- NULL
> a
 [1] 1000000.00  680000.00  170000.00  462400.00  115600.00  144500.00  314432.00   78608.00   98260.00  122825.00  213813.76   53453.44   66816.80
[14]   83521.00  104401.25  145393.36   36348.34   45435.42   56794.28   70992.85   88741.06
```

The problem is I need a list with the first number alone, the sum of the next two, sum of the next 3, sum of the next 4 etc. until I run out of numbers. I imagine it would look something like this:

```
c(sum(a[1]),sum(a[2:3]),sum(a[4:6])... etc.
```

Any help or a different way to do this would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a similar approach, using `rep(...)` and `by(...)`

```
n <- (-1+sqrt(1+8*length(a)))/2   # number of groups
groups <- rep(1:n,1:n)            # indexing vector
result <- as.vector(by(a,groups,sum))
result
# [1] 1000000.0  850000.0  722500.0  614125.0  522006.2  443705.3
```

Answer (score 2):

You should only need to go out to something on the order of `sqrt(length(vector))`. The seq function lets you specify a start integer and a length, so sending a sequence of integers to seq(1+x*(x-1)/2, length=x) should create the right set of sequences. It wasn't clear whether incomplete sequences at the end should return a result or NA so I put in na.rm=TRUE. You might decide otherwise. (You did not illustrate a dataframe but rather an ordinary numeric vector.

```
sumsegs <- function(vec) sapply(1:sqrt(2*length(vec)), function(x) 
                             sum( vec[seq(1+x*(x-1)/2, length=x)], na.rm=TRUE)  )

a <- scan()
 1000000.00 680000.00 170000.00 462400.00 115600.00 144500.00 314432.00 78608.00 98260.00 122825.00 213813.76 53453.44 66816.80  83521.00 104401.25 145393.36 36348.34 45435.42 56794.28 70992.85 88741.06
# 22: enter carriage return to stop scan input
#Read 21 items
 sumsegs(a)
#[1] 1000000.0  850000.0  722500.0  614125.0  522006.2  443705.3
```

I'm not exactly sure what the right upper limit on the number to send to the inner function. `sqrt(length(vec))` is too short, but `sqrt(2*length(vec))` seems to be "working" at lower numbers anyway.

```
> sapply( sapply(1:sqrt(2*100), function(x) seq(1+x*(x-1)/2, length=x) ), max)
 [1]   1   3   6  10  15  21  28  36  45  55  66  78  91 105
> sapply( sapply(1:sqrt(100), function(x) seq(1+x*(x-1)/2, length=x) ), max)
 [1]  1  3  6 10 15 21 28 36 45 55
```

This is a function that returns the last element in sequences so formed and making the factor 2.1 rather than 2 corrects minor deficiencies in the range of length 500-1000:

```
 tail(lapply( sapply(1:sqrt(2.1*500), function(x) seq(1+x*(x-1)/2, length=x) ), max),1 )
[[1]]
[1] 528
 tail(lapply( sapply(1:sqrt(2.1*500), function(x) seq(1+x*(x-1)/2, length=x) ), max),1 )
[[1]]
[1] 496
```

Going higher did not seem to degrade the "times 2" correction. There's probably some kewl number theory explanation for this.

```
tail(lapply( sapply(1:sqrt(2*100000), function(x) seq(1+x*(x-1)/2, length=x) ), max),1 )
[[1]]
[1] 100128
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively a much more naive method is:

```
    sums=colSums(data)
    n=0 # number of sums
    i=1 # currentIndex
    intermediate=0;
    newIndex=1;
    newVec <- vector()
    while(i<length(sums)) {
        for(j in i:(i+n)) {
            if(j<=length(sums)) 
                intermediate=intermediate+sums[j]
        }
        if(n>1){
        i=i+n+1;
        }
        else{
        i=i+1;
        }
        newVec=c(newVec, intermediate);
        intermediate=0;
        n=n+1;
    }
```